# calculate corner points on circle as gameobject rotates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a flat plane in 3d worldspace in Unity, I know the corner points and the pivot.  if I rotate that object I need to find the new corner points

So in the image below, lets say I know the vector3 of topleft and bottom right, but if I rotate that plane say 5 degrees clockwise how do I calculate the position of the new corners in worldspace?

I guess I'm looking for the mathematical way of doing this in c# if possible.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a rotation to the point (relative to the pivot) using `Quaternion.Euler`.
Then add the pivot Vector3 back to the result to get the final position.

```
Vector3 corner; // absolute position of the corner
Vector3 pivot; // absolute position of the pivot
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z);  // x, y, z rotation
Vector3 newCorner = pivot + rotation * (corner - pivot);  // absolute position of the corner after rotation
```

Comment: That's absolutely fantastic, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

big_bad_bison's answer is great. One thing I can add is that you can also:

1. Create game objects in the positions of the corners
2. Set them as children of the object you rotate (plane in this case)

Then in your script you can get their new positions by simply doing:

```cs
public GameObject corner;

void GetCornerPosition()
{
    return corner.transform.position;
}
```

That's just another way that lets you get those positions without any calculations.